# Sending Money directly via Bank Account From Paypal

Tags: paypal, european-union

How true is this ? I am a Novice to things like this. I added my Bank account (Euros) vis IBAN to paypal, now it says i can make Payments directly from my account, Please i want to know if its true and whats the maximum amount of money I can transfer should in case i want to make payment for some goods worth over EUR 100k is this possible via Paypal?

Comment: Which country are you in? PayPal may have different limits in different countries.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.paypal.com/us/selfhelp/article/What-is-the-maximum-amount-I-can-send-with-my-PayPal-account-FAQ732

> If your account is Verified, there’s no limit on the total amount of money you can send from your account. **You can send up to $60,000, but may be limited to $10,000, in a single transaction. (This amount can vary, though, depending on your currency.)**